# How to convert a string into an integer in python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.5

How can I convert this list into a list that does not have '-' in it and they are all integers?

```
List1 = ['978-0262133838','978-0262201-629','978-0321758927']
```

So the list will be something like

```
List1 = [9780262133838, 9780262201629, 9780321758927]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to show that you've put some effort into this.

Comment: Tried a list comprehension?

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple list comprehension with `.replace('-', '')`:

```
List1 = ['978-0262133838','978-0262201-629','978-0321758927']
print([x.replace('-','') for x in  List1])
# => ['9780262133838', '9780262201629', '9780321758927']
```

See the [Python 3 demo](http://ideone.com/rMk8GF)

Answer (score 0):

Most Pythonic way to achieve this is by using `map` with `lambda` function (to replace '-' with '' and then converting it into `int`):

```
>>> my_list = ['978-0262133838','978-0262201-629','978-0321758927']
>>> map(lambda x: int(x.replace('-', '')), my_list)
[9780262133838, 9780262201629, 9780321758927]
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help. if your list is:

```
List1 = ['978-0262133838','978-0262201-629','978-0321758927']
```

You can use a for loop like this one, and create a new list to keep the new numbers:

```
List2=[] #it is very important to have this list outside the for loop
For number in List1: #This does exactly what it says, you get the first number in the list, then you get the second and so on...
    number=number.replace("-","") # I use "" to refer strings, that's just how i learned.
    List2.append[int(number)]
```

And if the variable number just HAS to be List1, then just type

```
List1=List2
```

Hopefully it helps, good luck :D